# Tomcat SSL on port 8080

Tags: tomcat8, web.xml, server.xml

I have applied SSL on tomcat on port 443 but my manager asked me to apply it on port 8080 due to some constraints.
When I changed the port in connector to 8080 from 443, the server keeps on redirecting my request from https://domain_name:8080 to https://domain_name:8443.
Is there anything I can do to apply SSL on tomcat port 8080 without any redirection techniques?
Does it require any changes in "web.xml" as well?

Here is my Connector for 8080

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
                connectionTimeout="20000"
                scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
                keystoreFile="/home/my_user/SSL-Cert/sslKey.jks"
                keystorePass="pass121" clientAuth="false"
                keyAlias="ssl-Key" sslProtocol="TLS"
                />
```

When I change the port 8080 to 8082, it works fine without any redirection. Does that have to do anything with port 8080?

Comment: ? You do not have to change the port in the connector, what you must do is configure port 8080 to use HTTPS.

Comment: Please, edit your question and add the configuration of your `<Connector>`s. The redirect you are experiencing is caused by the lack of `secure="true"` on the connector.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz I have added the Connector

Comment: This configuration is correct, maybe your browser is caching a previous redirect.

Comment: Check also the logs: maybe you there is something else running on port 8080.